# Kurtosis function not playing nice

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm playing with Snowflake and when using the [KURTOSIS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/kurtosis.html) function I'm getting a divide by zero error :-(

Function works perfect if there's more than 1 distinct value (and more than 4 values):

```
select 
    kurtosis(bob) 
from 
    (select seq4() bob from table(generator(rowcount => 10)));
```

[image]

But fails when all values are identical .. in this case 1:

```
select 
    kurtosis(bob) 
from 
   (select 1 bob from table(generator(rowcount => 10)));
```

[image]

Aside from doing a count distinct or [HLL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hll.html) test prior to each evaluation can anyone suggest a solution?

I did see this [article](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5749) talking about Pandas "Rolling skewness and kurtosis fail on a sample of all equal values" but this was almost 10 years old way before Snowflake was even a pipe dream.

And the [SKEW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/skew.html) function has the identical problem.

My temporary yucky solution is:

```
select 
    DECODE(HLL(bob),1,0,SKEW(bob::FLOAT)) yucky_solution
from 
   (select 1 bob from table(generator(rowcount => 10)));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this reflects on how the `kurtosis` function works (regardless of Snowflake).

I tested this in Wolfram Alpha and on this online kurtosis calculator: https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/skewness/default.aspx

The numbers from 0 to 9 give the same value than Snowflake:

[image]

But 10 identical numbers return a NaN value:

[image]

---

Mathematically speaking, this is the formula for kurtosis:

[image]

Which you get by diving (something) by the standard deviation. The standard deviation of a series of identical numbers is 0 -- hence the division by 0 error.

---

Hence the SQL way to avoid an exception is to calculate the stddev first:

```sql
select 
    iff(stddev(bob)=0, null, kurtosis(bob))
from 
   (select 1 bob from table(generator(rowcount => 10))); 

-- null
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed by Snowflake that IFF/CASE `iff(stddev(bob)=0, null, kurtosis(bob))` will short-circuit i.e. does not try to evaluate true/false expression(branches) first?

Comment: I couldn't find a documented guarantee, but at least on all my tests expressions like `1/0` didn't cause a problem when in non executed conditional paths.

Comment: Thanks @FelipeHoffa … I would have preferred both skew and Kurtosis have returned null - consistent with behaviours when not enough values are presented (4 and 3 for kurtosis and skew accordingly).  But am grateful the functions exist :-)