# How to handle errors in functions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to build some stats on a table in snowflake and am using the `kurtosis()` and `skew()` functions. Since the calculations are under the hood (the divisions) I cannot use `nullif` to account for cases where I don't have enough distinct values which will return a `Division by zero` error. Does Snowflake have some sort of `iferror()` or `is_error()` function that I can use to return `null` or exclude from my table? Or could I build a UDF to do handle this scenario?

**EDIT**

This is the script I am using

```
select
    f.key colname,
    f.path path,
    typeof(f.value) type,
    count(distinct {player_col}) player_cnt,
    count(*) event_cnt,
    count(distinct f.value) unique_val_cnt,
    min(f.value) min,
    round(percentile_cont(.25) within group (order by iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) p25,
    round(avg(iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) mean,
    round(median(iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) med,
    round(percentile_cont(.75) within group (order by iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) p75,
    max(f.value) max,
    mode(f.value) mode,
    iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), max(f.value)-min(f.value), null) range,
    round(percentile_cont(.75) within group (order by iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) -
    round(percentile_cont(.25) within group (order by iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) iqr,
    round(stddev(iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value / 1000000, null)) * 1000000, 2) std,
    kurtosis(iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value, null)) kurtosis,
    skew(iff(typeof(f.value) in ('DECIMAL', 'INTEGER'), f.value, null)) skewness
from
    {json_table}, 
    lateral flatten({json_col}, recursive=>true) f
where
    typeof(f.value) not in ('OBJECT', 'NULL_VALUE', 'ARRAY') and f.path not like '%[%]%'
group by 1, 2, 3
order by 1, 2, 3
```

I get the below error

[image]

So I am guessing either some keys have less than 3 values or 1 distinct value across so it would return a DIV0# error.

Comment: @MikeWalton I've added the suggested edit

Comment: @AndreiBudaes well snowflake has `div0` function to handle division by zero error , but doesn't apply to your case , you better look into your data and filter out bad data before doing your math operations

Comment: Related: [Kurtosis function not playing nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506925/kurtosis-function-not-playing-nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a function like you asked in Snowflake. I think the SKEW and the KURTOSIS functions are causing the error because the total of the values is 0 for some groups.

You may try to use IFF and check the SUM of the data. Here is a simple test case:

```
create or replace table aggr(g number, k number);

insert into aggr values
    (1, 0),
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0);

select g,
IFF(sum(k) >0, skew(k), 0) skewness,
IFF(sum(k) >0, kurtosis(k), 0) kurtosis
from aggr
group by g;


+---+----------+----------------+
| G | SKEWNESS |    KURTOSIS    |
+---+----------+----------------+
| 1 |        0 | 0.000000000000 |
| 2 |        0 | 0.000000000000 |
+---+----------+----------------+

-- inserting more data to be able to calculate skew and kurtosis

insert into aggr values
    (1, 5),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 5),    
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3);

select g,
IFF(sum(k) >0, skew(k), 0) skewness,
IFF(sum(k) >0, kurtosis(k), 0) kurtosis
from aggr
group by g;


+---+--------------+-----------------+
| G |   SKEWNESS   |    KURTOSIS     |
+---+--------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 0.8076203007 | -1.272191860958 |
| 2 | 0.1364722935 | -0.775965134125 |
+---+--------------+-----------------+
```